# Create template page for printing - ionic 2

Tags: android, printing, ionic2

Ionic printer plugin use Printer.print([html string], [printer options]) function to get print out using mobile app.

I need to create html template and update some values dynamically and use template as input for the print function.

Can anyone have any idea how to do this?

I am using ionic 2 and android platform.

Comment: What exactly do you need? To know how to print? To know how to get the html for printing? How to have dynamic fields and print then? Do you've tryied something? Can you share your code if so?

Comment: I want to know how to get the html for printing. I want to get this html from separate file not within the my typescript file. And also need to have dynamic fields too.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly want to print.

I would probably just create an HTML template inside your code and then replace the values before printing.

Example:

```
class Page {

    template: string = `<h1>{title}</h1>
        <p>This is a paragraph</p>
        <p>{content}</p>`;

    getHTML(title, content) {
        let str = template;
        str = str.replace('{title}', title);
        str = str.replace('{content}', content);
        return str;
    }

    printPage(title, content) {
        let options = {};
        this.p.print(getHTML(title, content), options).then(onSuccess, onError);
    }

}
```